# Administrar precios de productos en inventario de acuerdo a su presentación en SQL

Tags: sql

He estado desarrollando un sistema que administre el inventario de una bodega distribuidora de papelería. Me encuentro en detalles a la hora de administrar el stock con el que se cuenta ya que dicha bodega maneja diversas presentaciones en cada uno de sus productos, ejemplo:

Producto: Hojas blancas t/c.

A la hora de recibir el material en bodega se realizará la captura de dicho producto en inventario (stock), en este caso sería 1 caja de hojas que contiene 5000 piezas (hojas) tomando esto como punto de partida se pretende dividir la existencia de inventario (stock) en las siguientes presentaciones para su posterior venta:

- Presentación 1: 1 hoja equivalente a una pieza o unidad. (De antemano sabemos que contamos con 5000 piezas u hojas).
- Presentación 2: Medio ciento (Equivalente a 50 hojas).
- Presentación 3: Un ciento (Equivalente a 100 hojas).
- Presentación 4: 1 paquete con 500 hojas.
- Presentación 5: Una caja con 10 paquetes (5000 hojas).

En cada presentación va a variar el precio del producto de acuerdo al tipo de cliente que se esté atendiendo.

Lo siguiente es la estructura de mis tablas para dar soporte a la administración de inventario:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_presentaciones(
id_presentacion INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
clave_presentacion TEXT NOT NULL,
nombre_presentacion TEXT NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE tbl_productos (
id_producto INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
id_departamento_producto INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_marca_producto INTEGER NOT NULL,
nombre TEXT NOT NULL,
precio_producto REAL NOT NULL,
precio_producto_impuestos REAL NOT NULL,
ruta_imagen TEXT NOT NULL,
fecha_registro DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
status INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id_departamento_producto) REFERENCES tbl_departamentos_productos(id_departamento_producto),
FOREIGN KEY(id_marca_producto) REFERENCES tbl_marcas_productos(id_marca_producto));


CREATE TABLE tbl_presentacion_producto(
id_presentacion_producto INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
id_producto INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_presentacion INTEGER NOT NULL,
cantidad INTEGER NOT NULL,
clave TEXT NOT NULL,
codigo_barras TEXT NOT NULL,
precio_oferta REAL NOT NULL,
precio_normal REAL NOT NULL,
precio_distribuidor REAL NOT NULL,
precio_mayoreo REAL NOT NULL,
precio_gobierno REAL NOT NULL,
status INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(id_producto) REFERENCES tbl_productos(id_producto),
FOREIGN KEY(id_presentacion) REFERENCES tbl_presentaciones(id_presentacion));

CREATE TABLE tbl_stock(
id_stock INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
id_producto INTEGER NOT NULL,
stock_real INTEGER NOT NULL,
stock_minimo INTEGER NOT NULL,
stock_demanda INTEGER NOT NULL,
fecha_entrada DATETIME NOT NULL,
stock_entrada INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

Lo anterior mostrado es la estructura que de mis tabas. Pero de acuerdo a mi análisis no alcanzo los objetivos deseados a la hora de administrar las presentaciones de cada producto.

Espero poder contar con su ayuda.

El objetivo es registrar cada unos de mis productos, en este caso el ejemplo es sobre hojas blancas, al registrarlas se pretende dividirla en sus diferentes presentaciones

[image: Interfaz que permite registrar los productos y a su vez definir cada una de sus presentaciones]

Comment: ok aca vamos mejor.. pero exactamente con que queres ayuda??? podrias agregar un der grafico?

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia. Si buscas ideas, recomendaciones, opiniones o ejemplos es mejor que uses Google. Si tienes un problema puntual, real y concreto con tu código, debes exponerlo claramente con un __[mcve]__.

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchísimas formas de hacer esto, y más que todo depende del crecimiento futuro que esperes obtener, el espacio de crecimiento de tu base y la cantidad de artículos.

Por lo que estás mostrando, ya tu base estaría (y lo digo en mi opinión), mal diseñada.

#### 1. Precios

Para manejar el precio, sería ideal contar con una tabla de listas de precios. De ésta forma, por cada producto `presentacion`, tendrías un precio en alguna lista, y si el día de mañana le quieres vender a los clientes `A`, a un precio y a los `B`, a otro, solo tienes que modificar la lista correspondiente. También, si quieres que una lista aumente, solo tenes que ejecutar un *query simple* sobre esa tabla.

Tener listas de precios te permite asignar distintos precios, sin importar a quién. Solo debes asignar una lista de precios al comprador y listo. Es más, podrías hasta asociar varias listas de precios a un comprador, y después, quien venda, decida la lista a utilizar.

#### 2. Productos

La tabla de productos estaría bien. El problema se origina cuando ocurre un ingreso de un producto del que ya tienes su *stock*, a un precio distinto. Eso en tu tabla no queda bien registrado.

Deberías tener una tabla `producto`, y una tabla `stock`, que diga las cantidades y a qué precio se adquirió cada una de esas, para que puedas calcular los retornos como corresponda.

#### 3. Presentación

La tabla de presentaciones, es un problema. Si permitís vender el mismo producto de varias formas, entonces tenes que tener siempre el producto en su mínima expresión (para poder dar las bajas de *stock*) y poder calcular el costo (el costo de compra en su precio unitario, sea cual sea), y después deberías tener una tabla `presentaciones`, que permita seleccionar en qué presentación se vende. Por supuesto, tu lista de precios debería tener el precio para cada presentación, o en su defecto saber qué precio tomar y cómo hacer los cálculos para el resto.

Más que una respuesta, esto es una recomendación. Todo esto depende del tamaño del proyecto y a qué querés llegar al final. No existe una única respuesta para esto, y lo de más arriba no es un análisis exhaustivo y puede contener errores.

Comment: Me parecen perfectas tus recomendaciones, y el proyecto tiene como objetivo dar una buena administración a cada uno de los productos que existan en inventario, tomando en cuenta sus diversas presentaciones y a su vez los precios correspondientes a dicha presentación. 
Me mencionas que existen diversas formas de realizar el proyecto e incluso entiendo que se puede dar una mejor estructura a las tablas. 
¿Podrías facilitarme una forma de realizarlo de manera más eficiente tal como me mencionas?

Comment: ¿O tendrás algún ejemplo que permita alcanzar esos objetivos o por lo menos que permita disipar las dudas que aún se mantienen?

Comment: Mas de lo que esta descripto ahi, es ya el trabajo del analista y del diseñador. estos son solo tips para encarrilar tu trabajo. No existen ejemplos porque ellos dependen del objetivo final, y si no todo nuestro trabajo como analistas no existiria mas.